# What is difference between Barrier and Guideline in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**Recently trying to implement `Constraint Layout` but I found `Barrier` and `Guideline` works same.** Both works like divider. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

### When to use barriers

Assume you have two `TextView` widgets with dynamic heights and you want to place a `Button` just below the tallest `TextView`:

[image: Task view]

The ***ONLY*** way to implement that directly in the layout is to use a horizontal `Barrier`. That `Barrier` allows you to specify a constraint based on the height of those two `TextView`s. Then you constrain the top of your `Button` to the bottom of the horizontal `Barrier`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#AAA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#DDD"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text_view,right_text_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

### When to use guidelines

Assume you want to restrict the above-mentioned `TextView` heights to 30% of screen height, no matter the content they have.

[image: Test view]

To implement that you should add horizontal `Guideline` with percentage position and constrain the `TextView` bottom to that `Guideline`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#AAA"
        android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#DDD"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

### Conclusion

The only difference between `Barrier` and `Guideline` is that `Barrier`'s position is flexible and always based on the size of multiple UI elements contained within it and `Guideline`'s position is always fixed.

Comment: a Valuable Answer!

Comment: The claim:

"The ONLY way to implement that directly in the layout is to use a horizontal Barrier."

is false. You can use a guideline for this, by having both text boxes be constrained below by a guideline. (I.e. `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"`

Comment: What happens to barrier when the visibility of reference views is gone. ?

Comment: @pandey_shubham In that case the barrier is created on the resolved position of the GONE widget. If you do not want to take into account GONE widgets you can set `barrierAllowsGoneWidgets` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and example. It is very useful!

Comment: I guess that by saying "ONLY" you refer on the same level, because you can easily do this by placing both views inside another layout with wrap content

Comment: For those whom this code doesn't show the barrier below the textviews, add app:layout_optimizationLevel="none" to the constraint layout.

Answer (score 26):

[Official documentation on Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier.html):

> A Barrier references multiple widgets as input, and creates a virtual guideline based on the most extreme widget on the specified side. For example, a left barrier will align to the left of all the referenced views.

[Training docs on Barrier](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-to-a-barrier):

> Similar to a guideline, a barrier is an invisible line that you can constrain views to. Except a barrier does not define its own position; instead, the barrier position moves based on the position of views contained within it. This is useful when you want to constrain a view to the a set of views rather than to one specific view.