# Wrapping text on a TextView that's constrained both on the left and on the right in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In a `ConstraintLayout`, I have 2 `TextView`'s side-by-side, and I want the right one to wrap text when it becomes too long so that it stays on the right of the left `TextView`, and doesn't overflow the container. Here is the code I have now:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10sp">

      ...

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/buildingTypeLabel"
           style="@style/FormLabel"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingTop="5sp"
           android:paddingBottom="5sp"
           android:text="@string/reference_view_building_type"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dateLabel"
           tools:text="Type de bâtiment" />

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/buildingType"
           style="@style/FormValue"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="end"
           android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:ellipsize="none"
           android:maxLines="100"
           android:scrollHorizontally="false"
           app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/buildingTypeLabel"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buildingTypeLabel"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date"
           tools:text="Bâtiments gouvernementaux" />
                ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But instead of putting text text on 2 lines in the right `TextView`, it overflows on the right:

[image: design preview]

Note that I have tried to add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to the right `TextView`, but it doesn't change anything.

How can I strictly enforce the right and left contraints of that `TextView` and have it wrap text to have a smaller width when needed?

Comment: try to change to `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` instead `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf`

Comment: @P.Juni your anwser was by far the easiest. I had mixed start/end and left/right constraints. You should add it as an answer so that I can select it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change to `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` instead `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ellipsize= "end" for the textview on the right that is extending text outside of the device screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use Guidelines
Guidelines are part of the constraint layout api.
Documentation are here ->
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline

This is how you can define your guideline in xml.

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_start"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="?dialogPreferredPadding" />
```

Guidlines can act as a differentiating factor between the two text views that you want to segregate .

Refer to this stackoverflow answer for much better understanding
**[What is difference between Barrier and Guideline in Constraint Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114672/what-is-difference-between-barrier-and-guideline-in-constraint-layout)**

The above link will also introduce you to barriers which is also part of constraint layout api which can also help you solve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the solution:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buildingTypeLabel"
        style="@style/FormLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:text="@string/reference_view_building_type"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/buildingType"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dateLabel"
        tools:text="Type de bâtiment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buildingType"
        style="@style/FormValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:maxLines="100"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/buildingTypeLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buildingTypeLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date"
        tools:text="Bâtiments gouvernementaux\n\nlef,le,flelf,le,fle," />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```