# Android constraint layout positioning 1 item below other

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, material-components-android

I have a constraint layout and the layout looks like this -

[image]

As you see the item `Pasta` and `10:10` are aligned one below  other. My layout for the same looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/food_item"
    style="@style/cardViewStyle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/food_name_label"
            style="@style/cardViewTextTitle"
            android:text="@string/food_name"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/food_name_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/food_name_value"
            style="@style/cardViewTextSubTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.39"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Pasta" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/food_intake_label"
            style="@style/cardViewTextTitle"
            android:text="@string/food_intake_time"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/food_intake_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/food_intake_value"
            style="@style/cardViewTextSubTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/food_intake_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/food_name_value"
            tools:text="10:10" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I have the id `food_name_value` horizontally aligned start and end to the parent.

My question is am I aligning the `food_name_value` and `food_intake_value` correctly one below the other because the label `Intake Time` is much longer than the label `Name` or what is the best way to align in my case?

Comment: if your values need to be at a specific distance you can constraint each of them together. also you can use `guide` to maintain a specific distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you need a [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier) here, with `barrierDirection="end"` and `constraint_referenced_ids="food_name_label,food_intake_label"`, Then align your `food_name_value, food_intake_value` with this barrier. Perfect explanation can be found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114672/what-is-difference-between-barrier-and-guideline-in-constraint-layout).

Comment: hi @fahad could u please help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview